# Como configurar DKIM

Tags: seguridad, dns

Buenos días,

Estoy tratando de configurar `DKIM` en mi hosting haciendo el registro `DNS` pero no se como hacerlo.

Actualmente dispongo del siguiente spf;
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all

Utilizo office 365 con godaddy

Podríais decirme que debería de añadir para crear las entradas de `DKIM`?

Gracias.

Saludos,

Comment: Hola, ¿Te refieres `DKIM`?, que no tiene nada que ver con `DCIM`. Tampoco tiene que ver con el `SPF`, son dos métodos diferentes. Uno basado en firmas y otro en delegación.

Comment: Si disculpa es dkim

Comment: ¿Que panel de alojamiento utilizas?

Comment: Tienes que decir lo que estás usando (Office 365, GSuite... etc) y si es posible el hosting. Así sin más es difícil responder a tu pregunta.

Comment: Utilizo office 365 con godaddy

Comment: David [aquí hay un tutorial completo](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-DNS-records-at-GoDaddy-for-Office-365-f40a9185-b6d5-4a80-bb31-aa3bb0cab48a) usando Office 365 y GoDaddy. Para **DKIM en específico, [mira estas instrucciones](https://o365info.com/how-to-enable-outbound-dkim-signing-for-your-domain-in-office-365-part-5-of-5/) a partir del paso 5**.